# Retrofit2 authentication error to IBM's Speech to Text

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, ibm-watson

I am trying to access IBM's Speech to Text service without using the library. I am using Retrofit with GSON.

The issue is in the authentication, which apparently does not occur correctly, returning code 401. From the [official documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-gettingStarted), the HTTP request should come in this format

```sh
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \
--data-binary @{path_to_file}audio-file.flac \
"{url}/v1/recognize"
```

When I test the `curl` command with my credentials, the service works fine.

This is the interface I'm using

```
interface SpeechToTextApi {

    @Multipart
    @POST("v1/recognize")
    fun speechToText(
        @Header("Authorization") authKey: String,
        @Part("file") filename: RequestBody,
        @Part voiceFile: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Call<List<SpeechToText>>
}
```

where I have the following data classes

```
data class SpeechToText(val results: List<SttResult>)
data class SttResult(val alternatives: List<RecognitionResult>, val final: Boolean)
data class RecognitionResult(val confidence: Float, val transcript: String)
```

and this is how I set up Retrofit

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(STT_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

private val service = retrofit.create(SpeechToTextApi::class.java)
```

while calling the actual service looks like this

```
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mp3"), file.name)
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestFile)
service
    .speechToText(getString(R.string.stt_iam_api_key), requestFile, body)
    .enqueue(object: Callback<List<SpeechToText>> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<SpeechToText>>, response: Response<List<SpeechToText>>) {
        val listOfStts = response.body()
        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: ${response.code()}")
        if (listOfStts != null) {
            for (stt in listOfStts) {
                for (res in stt.results) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Final value: ${res.final}")
                    for (alt in res.alternatives) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Alternative confidence: ${alt.confidence}\nTranscript: ${alt.transcript}")
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, alt.transcript, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<SpeechToText>>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: ${t.message}")
        t.printStackTrace()
    }
})
```

Recordings are MP3 files, for which I am sure they are stored correctly and accessible. I have replaced `audio/flac` with `audio/mp3` as well.

Issue seems to be in the way authentication works. Prior to the code I have shown above, I've used

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(STT_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val headers = request
                    .headers()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .add("Authorization", getString(R.string.stt_iam_api_key))
                    .build()
                val finalRequest = request.newBuilder().headers(headers).build()
                chain.proceed(finalRequest)
            }
            .build())
    .build()
```

but the same response code 401 persisted. Of course, the interface method lacked the `@Header` parameter.

Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am kind of saddened by the fact nobody was able to solve this one sooner, but here's the solution I came across by accident when working on a different project altogether.

As you can see from the `curl` command, authentication comes in the form of `username: password` pattern, in this case, username being `apikey` string and password is your API key.

So the way you should tackle this is by building your Retrofit instance this way:

```
fun init(token: String) {
    //Set logging interceptor to BODY and redact Authorization header
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    interceptor.redactHeader("Authorization")

    //Build OkHttp client with logging and token interceptors
    val okhttp = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .addInterceptor(TokenInterceptor(token))
        .build()

    //Set field naming policy for Gson
    val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)

    //Build Retrofit instance
    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(IBM_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()))
        .client(okhttp)
        .build()
}
```

and create this custom interceptor

```
class TokenInterceptor constructor(private val token: String) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val original = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder = original
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic("apikey", token))
            .url(original.url)
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

You need to use `Credentials.basic()` in order to encode credentials.

I really hope somebody with a similar issue stumbles across this and saves themselves some time.